# Android Studio Firebase invalid token in path

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-realtime-database

I'm getting an error of:

> 2022-06-20 16:32:37.238 6195-6195/com.example.couponsapp E/firebase: Error getting data
> java.lang.Exception: Invalid token in path
> at com.google.firebase.database.connection.PersistentConnectionImpl.lambda$get$0$com-google-firebase-database-connection-PersistentConnectionImpl(PersistentConnectionImpl.java:425)
> at com.google.firebase.database.connection.PersistentConnectionImpl$$ExternalSyntheticLambda2.onResponse(Unknown Source:6)
> at com.google.firebase.database.connection.PersistentConnectionImpl$6.onResponse(PersistentConnectionImpl.java:1292)
> at com.google.firebase.database.connection.PersistentConnectionImpl.onDataMessage(PersistentConnectionImpl.java:496)
> at com.google.firebase.database.connection.Connection.onDataMessage(Connection.java:167)
> at com.google.firebase.database.connection.Connection.onMessage(Connection.java:131)
> at com.google.firebase.database.connection.WebsocketConnection.appendFrame(WebsocketConnection.java:259)
> at com.google.firebase.database.connection.WebsocketConnection.handleIncomingFrame(WebsocketConnection.java:306)
> at com.google.firebase.database.connection.WebsocketConnection.access$500(WebsocketConnection.java:34)
> at com.google.firebase.database.connection.WebsocketConnection$WSClientTubesock$2.run(WebsocketConnection.java:86)
> at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:462)
> at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
> at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:301)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)

In path whenever I run the following code:

```
mDatabase.child("users").child(uuid).get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DataSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DataSnapshot> task) {
        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
            Log.e("firebase", "Error getting data", task.getException());
        }
        else {
            String studentID = String.valueOf(task.getResult().getValue());
            studentBox.setText(studentID);
        }
```

This is weird because the UUID is only the standard firebase generated UUID:

-N5-HbHttT0yUMO7ebxD

I have tried all online solutions and the code only worked after I removed the .child(uuid), but then I can't get the data I need.

Here is the JSON:

```
  "users": {
    "-N5-HbHttT0yUMO7ebxD": {
      "studentBal": 4000,
      "studentID": "P-2329",
      "studentName": "Hello World"
    },
    "HaMeP1-273299386": {
      "studentBal": 2800,
      "studentID": "P-1329",
      "studentName": "Ha Me"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a JSON file. You can simply get it by clicking the Export JSON in the overflow menu (⠇) in your [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/database/data).

Comment: What's the value of `uuid` inside `.child(uuid)`?

Comment: I don't immediately recognize that error message for the Realtime Database. Can you edit your question to include the complete error message **and stack trace**?

Comment: @AlexMamo -N5-HbHttT0yUMO7ebxD through a string.

Comment: What is the exact line that produces that error?

Answer (score 0):

You are using a wrong method to store a data of a user. Instead of `.child(UUID)` kindly use the `.child(currentUserID)` to save data. `CurrentUserId` is also a unique ID for all user so while getting the data use can pass as `mDatabase.child("users").child(currentUserID).get().addOnCompleteListener(......)` and so on in this way u can do it.